# How to iterate nested object in state to render the values on screen?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to render ownedStock state if there is value within stockInfo props. When there is value, stockInfo look like this [{name:"TSLA",price: 456}]. However, after useEffect runs ownedStock look like this [{stock:[{name:"TSLA",price: 456}]}]. When I try to map this like now, I get empty value. I've never seen any example of using Object.values... in return statement. How can I iterate ownedStock properly so values get reflected?

```
const StocksOwned = ({stockInfo}) => {
    const [ownedStock, setOwnedStock] = useState([]);
    console.log(stockInfo)

    const newStock = stock => {
        const newStocks = [ ...ownedStock, {stock}];
        setOwnedStock(newStocks)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(stockInfo[0]){
        newStock(stockInfo)
        } else {
            setOwnedStock([]);
        }
    },[stockInfo])

    console.log(ownedStock)
   return(
                    { {ownedStock} ? 
                    <TableBody>
                    {ownedStock.map((stock, index) => (
                        <StyledTableRow key = {index} >
                            <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                                {stock.name}
                            </StyledTableCell>
                            <StyledTableCell align="right">${stock.price}</StyledTableCell>
                            <StyledTableCell align="right">{stock.owned}</StyledTableCell>
                            <StyledTableCell align="right">
                                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" className={classes.margin} onClick={event => handleClick(event, index)}>
                                        SELL
                                    </Button>
                                </ThemeProvider>
                            </StyledTableCell>
                        </StyledTableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that `ownedStock = [{stock:[{name:"TSLA",price: 456}]}]`  so

```
ownedStock.map((myObj)=>{
    return myObj.stock.map((oneObj)=>{
        return (<div>{oneObj.name}</div>)
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your `newStock` function to add the new stock as an object into an array, like so

```
    const newStock = stock => {
        const newStocks = [ ...ownedStock, stock];
        setOwnedStock(newStocks)
    }
```

That will create a new array, with the `ownedStock` array copied over and add a new item to that array `stock`